# Headless task kills itself when app is killed

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-firebase

My service kills itself when the app is killed/closed.

Here's the background service I'm implementing (`bgMessaging.js`):

```
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';
// Optional flow type
import type { RemoteMessage } from 'react-native-firebase';

export default async (message: RemoteMessage) => {
    // handle your message
    console.log("RemoteMessage", message);

    const newNotification = new firebase.notifications.Notification()
        .android.setSmallIcon(message.data.icon)
        .android.setChannelId(message.data.channel_id)
        .android.setAutoCancel(true)
        .android.setBigText(message.data.body)
        .setNotificationId(message.messageId)
        .setBody(message.data.body);
    if(message.data.title != undefined)
        newNotification.setTitle(message.data.title);
    if(message.data.color != undefined)
        newNotification.android.setColor(message.data.color);
    if(message.data.bigPicture != undefined)
        newNotification.android.setBigPicture(message.data.bigPicture);
    if(message.data.largeIcon != undefined)
        newNotification.android.setLargeIcon(message.data.largeIcon);

    firebase.notifications().displayNotification(newNotification);

    return Promise.resolve();
}
```

Here's my `index.js`:

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './app';
import bgMessaging from './bgMessaging';

const app = new App();

AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('RNFirebaseBackgroundMessage', () => bgMessaging);
```

According to the documentation of [react-native-firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase), this implementation should work. However, `RNFirebaseBackgroundMessage` service kills itself when the app is killed/closed.

Is this due to the implementation of `react-native-navigation`? This is an exact [example](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/tree/master/old-example-redux) of my implementation of react-native-navigation.

Using react-native@0.53.3 and react@16.2.0

Please help.

Comment: You need to write some native code and register the service in your manifest file, have you done that?

Comment: Are you referring to adding the <service> as per [Background-Messages](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.2.x/messaging/android#(Optional)-Background-Messages) ? Yes, I've done that. Is there anything else required? If yes, can you refer me to that?

Comment: I would try debugging the app from Android Studio, have a good look at the app log, I'm pretty sure it will contain some helpful information :)

Comment: I've tried that, this is the message I get: `W GCM : broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.mycustomapp (has extras) }` . Here's the link to the issue posted in react-native-firebase repository: [Not receiving fcm data-only message when app is closed](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1238)